# How to join and get 4 results

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables

```
A
artnr grp name
1 FlowerA NameA
2 FlowerB NameB
3 FlowerC NameC
4 FlowerD NameD

B
artnr eigenschap waarde
1 color Red
2 color Null
4 color Yellow
4 Height 30
```

How do I get 4 results with color?

```
Select A.Artnr,
       A.grp,
       A.name,
       B.waarde
from A
left join B on B.Artnr = A.Artnr 
where B.Eigenschap = 'color'
```

My problem is that table B doesn't have artnr 3, Artnr 2 is empty( Is Null) that's no problem. I have problems when a record doesn't exist in both tables.

I would like the following result:

```
A left join b
artnr grp name   waarde
1 FlowerA NameA  red
2 FlowerB NameB  NULL
3 FlowerC NameC  NULL   -- Droptopp: I want to see this even not in table B
4 FlowerD NameD  yellow
```

I get 3 rows, missing row with artnr 3 it's because it's not in table B I think. So how do I get a result with 4 rows and the row with artnr 3 an empty cell in the column color?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with records "that don't exist in both tables"? What is a record, that does not exists in both tables?

Comment: @Droptopper,What is your expected result..?

Comment: What is expected Result

Comment: artnr is same to both table so use alias when selecting data e.g
Select A.Artnr as aID,
       A.grp as grp,
       A.name as name,
       B.color as bcolor
from A
left join B on B.Artnr = A.Artnr

Comment: I want 4 results I want artnr 3 to show up as well even it is not in both tables. This way I can see what I miss. I don't want table B filled with all records from table A and color as empty (Is Null)

Comment: @Droptopper Left join does just that. Your current SQL will show a line for both `2` and `3` and both will show `color` as `NULL`.

Comment: What result DO you get? Because you should be getting a row for artnr 3 already.

Comment: I get 3 rows, missing row with artnr 3 it's because it's not in table B I think. So how do I get a result with 4 rows and the row with artnr 3 an empty cel in the kolom color..

Comment: I changed table B, it's now how it is.. I want the 4 rows from table A and the colors out of table B if exist or else Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the `WHERE`. This statement:

```
Select A.Artnr,
   A.grp,
   A.name,
   B.eigenschap,
   B.waarde
from A
left join B on B.Artnr = A.Artnr
```

would return a row for article 3, which is

```
3 FlowerC NameC NULL NULL
```

after that you filter for `eigenschap = 'color'`, which removes that row from the final result set since `eigenschap` is `NULL`. Move that condition to the join condition:

```
Select A.Artnr,
   A.grp,
   A.name,
   B.waarde
from A
left join B on B.Artnr = A.Artnr AND
B.eigenschap = 'color'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Artnr, A.grp, A.name, B.waarde
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B 
ON (A.artnr = B.artnr)
```

[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)